# How to improve the following code to get rid of the warning messages?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, code-review

I have to solve the following initial Value problem
$$y'=\frac{2xy}{y^2-1}, \quad y(2)=1$$

so, I wrote the following code to solve it

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[x] == (2*x*y[x])/(y[x]^2 - 1), y[2] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

and I received the following answer
[image].

My question is, how could I improve my code, so I will not have these warning messages?

Comment: They are not errors, just warnings that Mathematica may not have found all solutions.  It does give you an answer that satisfies the differential equation and boundary condition.  You should plot the solution to determine if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}  & =f\left(  x,y\right)  \\
& =\frac{2xy}{y^{2}-1}\\
y\left(  2\right)    & =1
\end{align*}

We see at $y=1,x=2$ the $f\left(  x,y\right)  $ is not defined. Hence
existence and uniqueness theorem does not apply. There is no guarantee that
unique solution exists on an interval that includes $y\left(  2\right)  =1$.
There could be unique solution, no solution at all, or infinite number of
solutions. Theory says nothing about this since it does not apply. Only way is
to solve it and find out.

Integrating the ode gives

\begin{align}
\int\frac{y^{2}-1}{y}dy  & =\int2xdx\nonumber\\
\frac{y^{2}}{2}-\ln y  & =x^{2}+c\tag{1}%
\end{align}

Applying IC

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}-\ln1  & =4+c\\
c  & =\frac{1}{2}-4\\
& =-\frac{7}{2}%
\end{align*}

Hence solution (1) becomes

$$
\frac{y^{2}}{2}-\ln y=x^{2}-\frac{7}{2}
$$

This is an implicit solution. You can leave the solution implicit. But `DSolve` always tries to find explicit solution and has no option to ask for implicit solution only.

To obtain explicit solution

```
sol = -7/2 + x^2 - 1/2*y[x]^2 + Log[y[x]] == 0
Solve[sol, y[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets checks if both solutions satisfy the ode and the IC. It turns out only one of these does. Which is why DSolve returns one of them and not both.

```
ode = y'[x] == (2*x*y[x])/(y[x]^2 - 1)
ic = y[2] == 1
ode /. y -> 
   Function[{x}, -I  Sqrt[ProductLog[-E^(7 - 2 x^2)]]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ode /. y -> 
   Function[{x}, I  Sqrt[ProductLog[-E^(7 - 2 x^2)]]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ic /. y -> 
   Function[{x}, -I  Sqrt[ProductLog[-E^(7 - 2 x^2)]]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ic /. y -> 
   Function[{x}, I  Sqrt[ProductLog[-E^(7 - 2 x^2)]]] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So only the solution with the negative sign satisfy the ode and the IC and that is what `DSolve` returned.

Compare to output of `DSolve`

```
ode = y'[x] == (2*x*y[x])/(y[x]^2 - 1)
ic = y[2] == 1
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In Maple, it has an option to return implicit solution if a user wants. I hope in future version of Mathematica this can be added. Here is maple's solution

```
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=(2*x*y(x))/(y(x)^2-1);
ic:=y(2)=1;
sol:=dsolve([ode,ic]);
```

[image]

Here is the implicit one

```
 sol:=dsolve([ode,ic],y(x),'implicit');
```

[image]

As to the warning message, this is produced by Solve due to having `Log[y]`. (which is a function of `y`) Here is a much simpler example

```
Solve[y^2 == Log[y], y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or even

```
 Solve[y == Log[y], y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All produce same message. Not sure now if there is a way to add assumptions or other trick to avoid these warning messages. But as mentioned in comment, these are  warning and not errors. But always good to look at them even if they are just warning just in case.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try inverse problem

```
X = Values@
DSolve[{ (y ^2 - 1) == x'[y] (2*x[y]*y ) , x[1] == 2}, x , y][[1,1]]  

Plot[X[y], {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]